# Remove dbo. schema prefix from SQLServer (2005) Management Studio's Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'd like to remove the `dbo` prefix from the Object Explorer so I can press the <kbd>S</kbd> key and go to the tables that begin with <kbd>S</kbd>; having `dbo` there is irritating (to me).

I have searched on the net and there was an answer at *that other site* that said I should use <kbd>F7</kbd> in the summary tab, but I couldn't find a summary tab, and pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> in the Object Explorer didn't work for me.

Comment: I wonder if it is the 98 or 99 percent of management studio users, that hates that `.dbo` prefix. :)

Comment: I hate it too. Yes, I want to know what schema it is, but couldn't it be displayed as a tree node? Like dbo -> all dbo tables as children without a prefix? Doesn't seem very far-fetched of an idea to me. If someone wants to write an addon that does that, I bet a lot of people would appreciate it. I might even try my own hand at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can't in the Object Explorer, but the Object Explorer Details doesn't prefix the dbo.

Comment: Object Explorer Details is great ...now only if it could be docked with object explorer ;-)  ^d^d ...Right click on the tab and choose the "Dockable" option.

Comment: Its almost a perfect replacement, yet no cigar. Can we make the Object explorer Details NOT read from the db, on selection of said db? Right now, I have a two second delay on any action in the Details window. Maybe someone should make an extension.

Answer (score 5):

I just found out you can enter, for example, `dbo.f`, and it navigates to the first table that starts with `f`.

Comment: That's the way we go directly to the item we need in any list. OP and others are looking for some way by which they only have to type `f` and not `dbo.f`